# how to open files in folder that start with (dot) - ( or hidden files )

Tags: android

SOLVED :

> that was my mistake in generate file names, files with space in name didn't play ( unicode problem )

---

i want to lunch files after download with different apps like pdf reader, video player, audio player , etc...

my download path start with ( dot ) like "sdcard/.foldername/file1.mp4"

when i want to lunch that file with default video player, a message show up that "can't play this video" but when i change the path to "sdcard/foldername/file1.mp4" apps can play this file.

my code to lunch file :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));

String filename = _File;
String filenameArray[] = filename.split("\\.");
String extension = filenameArray[filenameArray.length - 1];


String mimeType = "";
if (extension != null) {
mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
intent.setType(mimeType);
}

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimeType);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

"file" is path : "sdcard/.foldername/files1.mp4"

EDIT : 
PATH IS "/sdcard/.foldername/files1.mp4"

Some Apps can play files ( like apollo player )
and some apps like foxit pdf can't open pdf files in this path

Comment: `download path start with ( dot ) like "sdcard/.foldername/file1.mp4"`. No that path starts with an s. Wrong path. That should be:  "/sdcard/.foldername/file1.mp4"

Comment: it's working for me with the exact path, your code and File file = new File("/sdcard/.foldername/.test.mp4"); It doesnt work for all dotted-like folder like this or only this one ?

Comment: actually path is "/sdcard/.foldername/file1.mp4" 
file with ".mp3" extension and appollo player work correctly
but foxit pdf can't open pdf file in this path
i think some apps can't play this path files